# how can i load a swf into another swf using php readfile and retain the url parameters?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, readfile, url-parameters

I am using php to read a file (specified by a cookie on the users machine) with the function readfile().
the file I am reading is an actionscript 3 flash file that depends on a configuration file appended to the url to function properly.

ex: http://www.pathToFlash.com/file.swf?CONFIG_URL=http://www.pathToConfig.com/config.xml

When I use readfile - the headers are set properly and the swf is returned to the browser which then runs it. I have discovered that using this method the config file (CONFIG_URL) has to be appended to the php file's url to be read properly by the swf - as the swf considers the path to the php file it's own.

This is fine when these are the only two elements involved - but when loading the php>read(swf) combination into another swf - the 'read' swf returns a url that is null (using this.root.loaderInfo.url) and therefore fails to execute properly as there is no config file (CONFIG_URL).

My question is: how can I load in a swf file from a php page (using readfile, fopen, whatever) and pass in $get parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:`this.root.loaderInfo.url` needs to be: `this.root.loaderInfo.parameters.url`.

Second of all `root.loaderInfo.parameters` can be only accessed only from root swf.
This means that you can not say inside swf to php: load.php?swf=second.swf&someParameter=1234, and parse some parameter for the loaded swf directly.

The solution ( there is more thant one ) is:

1. You need to set all this parameters for the root.swf ( when you loading it )

mainConfig=xml/config.xml
secondSWFconfig=xml/secondconfig.xml

and etc...

1. in the second.swf which will be loaded by root.swf you need to create function:

   public function set parameters ( value : Object )
   {
      // here all the assigment of the parameters
   }
2. In the root.swf function which is launched after second.swf is loaded:

   private function onSecondSWFLoaded ( e : Event ) : void
   {
      e.currentTarget.content['parameters'] = this.root.loaderInfo.parameters;
   }

ANd then in the second swf you will be gettin these parameters and after them you can launch everything you need.

regards.